# Load different json files in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 local json files that are similar. I want to load each of them at different times in flutter. Is there anyway to pass variables in future for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can load anything that is included as an Asset in your app. So for example, you could put this in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  assets:
    - config/ordinary.json
    - config/special.json
```

Then you could load either of those in your code, like this:

```dart
final config = await DefaultAssetBundle
  .of(context)
  .loadString('config/ordinary.json');
```